# Howto design models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I am trying to create a rails app where each user model can have a single team model and a single stadium model and may compete in a single league. Each team contains players, a single trainer, a single cook etc. and each stadium contains one hotel, one carpark etc..

Understandably, all these players, trainers etc.. are going to affect the team's winning chance and levels of carpark and hotel etc. is going to affect the money earned in a period of time.

The problem (originating from the fact that I am not a programmer at all) is that I can't decide whether all these players, trainers, cooks, hotels, carparks etc. should be separate models or just attributes of team and stadium models. After all, if a user upgrades a hotel from level 1 to 2, the stadium's value may be multiplied by 1.2 for example. But I suppose that for more realistic calculations of match winning conditions (goals, fauls, injuries etc.) it may be more suitable to have separate models. So I know it depends on functions or game mechanics. But since I have no experience inthese areas, I cannot plan the base. Can anyone give suggestions?

Can anyone clarify this issue? I have read many MVC articles but I still have difficulty in understanding MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is a question about models only, not about MVC. Here are some thoughts when models are needed (or not):

- Is there a primitive (String, Number, Date) value that you want to hold, there is no need for an additional model. So e.g. if you only want to store the stadiums value (whatever that is), there is no need to create a `Stadium` model for that.
- If your possible model has more than one value you want to keep, there will be a need to create an additional model. It looks not natural to keep e.g. `stadium_value`, `stadium_name`,  `stadium_size`, ...
- If your possible model has not only attributes, but behavior, the natural place to define that behavior (as methods) is the model class. So if you want to calculate e.g. the `value` of your stadium by combining other attributes of your model, the model `Stadium` is the natural place for that.

This is all independent from Rails and will be true for all object-based or object-oriented languages.

**Addition**
It is difficult to decide without your whole knowledge. At the end, we talk about how to retrieve and store model objects from the database, and how to display them in a browser. As long as a possible model object is **only** a single value (like the trainers name), it is faster, easier to implement and to show in the browser. It breaks at the moment you need more than the trainers name then. So make enough design upfront to have it clear which are real model objects, and react as early as possible when you see that you have missed one.

PS: Without being a programmer at all, you will face a hard time implementing it with Rails ...

Comment: If I understood correctly, you suggest that only a user, a team and a stadium model is enough, since carpark, hotel etc is going to store a single value. But the team model is not suitable since trainer model for example is going to include many attributes like name, defense_bonus, attack_bonus etc. So no need to clutter attributes more than necessary.

Comment: Added something to my answer, hope it is a little more clear.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was thinking about to ask what you exactly added!